# MVVM Notifying Property Changed Back

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have a MVVM based application(Not using any particular mvvm library or framework) with a few buttons I want to enable and disable depending on if a method is running. I set up a bool property on the ViewModel, "ProcessRunning":

```
bool _ProcessRunning = false;
/// <summary>
/// Whether A Process Is Currently Taking Place
/// </summary>
public bool ProcessRunning
{
    get
    {
        return _ProcessRunning;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_ProcessRunning != value)
        {
            _ProcessRunning = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProcessRunning");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a series of buttons with styles binding them to this property as such:

**Button:**

```
<Button Name="btn_AddMore" Content="More" Style="{StaticResource ExecuteButtons}"
        ToolTip="Enumerate Customer Folders To Get More Customer And Job Options"
        Command="{Binding AddFolderOptions}"/>
```

**Style:**

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ExecuteButtons">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="700"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFA0A0A0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEEEEEE"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ProcessRunning, Converter={StaticResource Inverse}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the binding works as expected apart from when I change it during a method that does other things as such:

```
private void AddOptionsFromFolders(object Parameter)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessRunning = true;
        Transfer_Workers.Program.Processes.AddFolderChoices(ref _LocalSettings);
```

In this case the View isn't updated until after AddOptionsFromFolders has exited.

I found through a couple other questions that the UI thread is being block during this method call and doesn't get freed up to update until the method is complete so I tried this:

```
private void AddOptionsFromFolders(object Parameter)
{
    try
    {
        ProcessRunning = true;

        //Transfer_Workers.Program.Processes.AddFolderChoices(ref _LocalSettings);

        Thread test = new Thread(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); ProcessRunning = false; });
        test.Start();
```

In this case the UI is updated when ProcessRunning is set to true but when the "test" thread completes and should set ProcessRunning to false, the UI doesn't update.

I have my ViewModel inherited from a main view model and that from a base view model where I have RaisePropertyChanged declared:

```
internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why the UI doesn't update when ProcessUpdated is set back to false. No Exceptions are thrown and there are no warnings or errors within the output window (Visual Studio 2013 Pro).

My intended outcome is that while the method is running the buttons will be disabled and while it's not the buttons are enabled. If anyone can shed some light on the issue at hand here or even suggest a different way of notifying the View of a property being changed in a more async fashion I would greatly appreciate it.

Also if there's anything I wasn't clear on or information I left out just ask and I will get that to you asap.

Comment: As an aside Visual Studio 2013 Pro is an editor and believe it or not, it has no direct affect on the output of the program; it only dictates what .Net version can be used. Any post on SO would be better suited to put the actual .Net version being compiled against in the list of tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're updating the property from a background thread.  The UI can't be updated from a thread other than the UI thread, so your property change is ignored.

You can do this using async/await:

```
ProcessRunning = true;
await Task.Run(() => 
{ 
    // do work here 
});
ProcessRunning = false;
```

The synchronisation context is captured when the `Task` is awaited, so it resumes execution on the UI thread.

For disabling buttons, however, you should probably just ensure that `CanExecute` on your command returns false until the command has finished executing.

Comment: I thought about this however I can't use anonymous methods to run the task because I need to pass a parameter by reference within the action taking place. Also I don't want the ProcessRunning to be set to false until the task is indeed finished.

Comment: How about if I set up an event the UI thread had a handler on that was raised when the process finished and the property was reset to false, should that work?

Comment: Then capture the parameter as a closure?  e.g. `Task.Run(() => AddFolderChoices(ref _LocalSettings))`.  It won't set `ProgressRunning=false` until the task is complete.  An event won't help you as this will be raised and handled on the same thread.

Comment: Alright I see what you're saying. Created I new command object called primed command where I pass it two actions, one to prime the value(set process  running to true) then the other using Task.Run which invokes the  main action and passes the parameter and it works for the most part. There is a slight bug doing this that not all the binds refresh at the same time for some reason but thank you very much this worked for me. :) I'll have to take a look back into the difference between thread and task I guess.

Answer (score 0):

One should avoid reading and writing *directly* to variables which may be tied to the GUI thread.

For this situation, **inside** and at the end of your thread, use the dispatcher to notify the gui thread of the change such as

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
     DispatcherPriority.Background,
      new Action(() => ProcessRunning = false));
```

I ran into similar when I tried to read from a background thread. Read about my experience here [C# WPF: Linq Fails in BackgroundWorker DoWork Event](http://omegacoder.com/?p=636)

---

### Secondary Thoughts

Also keep in mind that with multi-threading, you may be running into a race condition.

Can one truly eliminate that another thread may be changing the flag as well? Or that the background thread is actually finishing faster than expected and setting the value first before it was initially set?

Race conditions can be insidious and they do occur.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken in the link you have you were executing a method as an event handler possibly on the code behind? And writing directly to the UI, ProcessRunning as described in my question is a property on my view model which the UI binds to with the windows datacontext set to the view model. If I am misunderstanding please let me know though. Also I tried implement the application dispatch carrying out the task but to no avail.

Comment: As I inquired in Charles Mager's answer, how about if I set up an event the UI thread had a handler on that was raised when the process finished and the property was reset to false, should that work?